# Libor Market Model in negativ interest environment

Tags: rates, modelling

I try to implement the Libor Market Model in a negative interest environment. As the LMM is a model which assumes a lognormal distribution of forward rates, in its basic form, it cannot deal with this setting.
I know that there is a normal (Bachelier) version of the LMM, but I cannot find details about it and its implementation. Right now I use the following formula under the forward measure for the dynamik of the forward rates:
[image]
[image]

How do I have to adjust this, when I want to use the normal LMM?

Comment: If you look in the literature for Generalized Vasicek models, they are gaussian rather than exponentiated gaussian.  Like LMM they match the market "exactly".  Note that formulations I have seen in the literature are all in continuous time so you have to translate a little.